# Modify existing object with new partial JSON data using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

Consider the below example program

```
var calendar = new Calendar
{
    Id = 42,
    CoffeeProvider = "Espresso2000",
    Meetings = new[]
    {
        new Meeting
        {
            Location = "Room1",
            From = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            To = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-01-01T01:00:00Z")
        },
        new Meeting
        {
            Location = "Room2",
            From = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-01-01T02:00:00Z"),
            To = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-01-01T03:00:00Z")
        },
    }
};

var patch = @"{
        'coffeeprovider': null,
        'meetings': [
            {
                'location': 'Room3',
                'from': '2014-01-01T04:00:00Z',
                'to': '2014-01-01T05:00:00Z'
            }
        ]
    }";

var patchedCalendar = Patch(calendar, patch);
```

The result of the `Patch()` method should be equal to `calendar` except as changed by `patch`. That means; `Id` would be unchanged, `CoffeeProvider` would be set to `null` and `Meetings` would contain a single item located in Room3.

1. How does one create a general `Patch()` method that will work for
   any object (not just the example Calendar object) deserializable by
   Json.NET?
2. If (1) this is not feasible, what would be some restrictions that would make it feasible and how would it be implemented?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question.  Do you want to modify your object, or clone it and modify the clone?

Comment: Modifying actually works best in my scenario. However, if there is built in functionality for cloning I wouldn't mind knowing how to do that as well. If there is no built in functionality, I could just deep clone the object (for example by serializing+deserializing) before patching it.

Comment: deep-cloning via Json.Net is what I would suggest.  Updated answer with a prototype.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want [`JsonSerializer.Populate()`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate_1.htm) or its static wrapper method [`JsonConvert.PopulateObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_PopulateObject.htm):

> Populates the JSON values onto the target object.

For instance, here it is updating an instance of your `Calendar` class:

```
public static class TestPopulate
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var calendar = new Calendar
        {
            Id = 42,
            CoffeeProvider = "Espresso2000",
            Meetings = new[]
            {
                new Meeting
                {
                    Location = "Room1",
                    From = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    To = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-01-01T01:00:00Z")
                },
                new Meeting
                {
                    Location = "Room2",
                    From = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-01-01T02:00:00Z"),
                    To = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-01-01T03:00:00Z")
                },
            }
        };

        var patch = @"{
    'coffeeprovider': null,
    'meetings': [
        {
            'location': 'Room3',
            'from': '2014-01-01T04:00:00Z',
            'to': '2014-01-01T05:00:00Z'
        }
    ]
}";
        Patch(calendar, patch);

        Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(calendar, Formatting.Indented));
    }

    public static void Patch<T>(T obj, string patch)
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        using (var reader = new StringReader(patch))
        {
            serializer.Populate(reader, obj);
        }
    }
}
```

And the debug output produced is:

```
{
  "id": 42,
  "coffeeprovider": null,
  "meetings": [
    {
      "location": "Room3",
      "from": "2014-01-01T04:00:00+00:00",
      "to": "2014-01-01T05:00:00+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update**

If you want to copy first, you could do:

```
    public static T CopyPatch<T>(T obj, string patch)
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        var copy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);

        using (var reader = new StringReader(patch))
        {
            serializer.Populate(reader, copy);
        }

        return copy;
    }
```