# vb.net Class constructor of itself

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

I have a wrapper class to help deserialize incoming json messages.
At the moment I am using it like this.

```
Dim oXMessage As XMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of XMessage)(message)
```

I wanted to create a constructor for the class so I can instantiate it more cleanly. Like this

```
Dim oXMessage as XMessage = New XMessage(message)
```

I have tried the below constructor but it does not work.
Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
Public Class XMessage
    <JsonProperty("e")> Public MessageType As String
    <JsonProperty("data")> Public MessageData As Object
    <JsonProperty("ok")> Public MessageOk As String

    Public Sub New(message As String)
        Me = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Me)(message)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511675/modify-existing-object-with-new-partial-json-data-using-json-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reassign the *value* of [`Me`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/me-my-mybase-and-myclass#me) in the constructor since that is the object currently being constructed.  But you can call   [`JsonConvert.PopulateObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_PopulateObject.htm) to initialize its *contents*:

```
Public Class XMessage
    <JsonProperty("e")> Public MessageType As String
    <JsonProperty("data")> Public MessageData As Object
    <JsonProperty("ok")> Public MessageOk As String

    Public Sub New(message As String)
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(message, Me)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o4gOV7).

Answer (score 0):

The `Me` keyword refers to the current instance and cannot be the target of assignment.

Instead what you may want to do is to create a new object, deserialize it, and copy the new objects member variables to the current instance.

**Edit: without the helper functions**

```
Public Class XMessage

    <JsonProperty("e")> Public MessageType As String
    <JsonProperty("data")> Public MessageData As Object
    <JsonProperty("ok")> Public MessageOk As String

    Public Sub New(message As String)
        Dim other = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of XMessage)(message)
        Me.MessageType = other.MessageType
        Me.MessageData = other.MessageData
        Me.MessageOk = other.MessageOk
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Original:**

```
Public Class XMessage

    <JsonProperty("e")> Public MessageType As String
    <JsonProperty("data")> Public MessageData As Object
    <JsonProperty("ok")> Public MessageOk As String


    Public Sub New(message As String)
        Dim other as XMessage= Deserialize(message)
        Me.MessageType = other.MessageType
        Me.MessageData = other.MessageData
        Me.MessageOk = other.MessageOk
    End Sub


    Public shared Function Deserialize(message as String) as XMessage
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of XMessage)(message)
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Serialize(message As XMessage) As String 
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message)
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a clever syntax that would avoid the creation of another instance. This solution works perfectly though - thanks.

Comment: Actually now I test it properly, I can see that this approach creates an infinite recursion.

Comment: There should be no recursion here if you copy the code as-is.

Comment: added a simplified version without the helper methods

Comment: thanks for your time, maybe I am describing it wrong. When I create the objext with "{""e"":""connected""}" and step through. 1.The New is called with the message="{""e"":""connected""}". 2. Then the Dim line is executed. 3. next the New sub is called again with message=nothing. 4. the Dim line is executed and errors due to message=nothing.

Comment: just realised that an overload New() will solve that - sorry I'm a noob.